# i want my sidebar stay open when refreshed

Tags: javascript

I used the method bellow for opening and closing a tab by clicking the button using java script.

here is the html:

```
<div class="header_nav_icon" onclick="chartButton()" >
    <i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>
</div>

<div id="chart_sidebar" >
    <a href="#">charts</a>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#chart_sidebar{
   display: none;
   top: 55;
   width: 340px;
   height: 100%;
   float:left;
}
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
function chartButton() {

   var x = document.getElementById("chart_sidebar");

   if (x.style.display === "block") {
       x.style.display = "none";
   } else {
       x.style.display = "block";
   }

}
```

When I click the tab, it opens but when I refreshed the page it revert back to its default setup.

I want the browser remember the sidebar to stay open even it is refreshed.

Comment: you have to use cookies or LocalStorage

Comment: welcome to javascript, when you refresh your browser you completely parse and execute your scripts again. you can use cookies or local storage or even more things to store this external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please.. be simple ;)

```js
const ChartSideBar = document.getElementById("chart_sidebar");

if (!sessionStorage.getItem('sideBarDisplay')) {
  sessionStorage.sideBarDisplay = 'none';
}

ChartSideBar.style.display = sessionStorage.sideBarDisplay;


function chartButton() {
  ChartSideBar.style.display = (ChartSideBar.style.display==='block') ? 'none' : 'Block';
  sessionStorage.sideBarDisplay = ChartSideBar.style.display;
}
```

```css
    #chart_sidebar{
      display: none;
      top: 55;
      width: 340px;
      height: 100%;
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header_nav_icon" onclick="chartButton()" >
  <i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>
</div>

<div id="chart_sidebar" >
  <a href="#">charts</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML5's localStorage to store the state of the side bar which needs to  persist until explicitly deleted.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You could also use sessionStorage if you are ok with the session info being lost when the browser is closed. It persists over page reloads and restores.

// Sample

```
// This is for when the page loads
const sideBarElement = document.getElementById("chart_sidebar")
sideBarElement.style.display = (sessionStorage.sideBarOpen ? sessionStorage.sideBarOpen : false) ? "block" : "none"

function chartButton() {
  const sideBarOpen = sessionStorage.sideBarOpen ? sessionStorage.sideBarOpen : false
  const sideBarElement = document.getElementById("chart_sidebar")

  sideBarElement.style.display = sideBarOpen === true ? "none"
  sessionStorage.sideBarOpen = !sideBarOpen
}
```

Comment: Does this script simply replace my current script for opening and closing or i have to place them all together?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the URL to save such state. When using the URL, you can share the link with the sidebar open or closed with others, making them see the same things you see without having them click around to follow you.

Usually this means you need to manipulate the browsers URL (for example [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) when toggling the sidebar) and reading the URL when loading / opening the webpage to check what state to set for the sidebar initially.

I suspect you want a client-side solution and not change your server to handle different URLs, so I'd recommend using the hash (`#`) part of the URL, which is not sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your JavaScript, add this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("chartSidebarStyle")) {
        document.getElementById("chart_sidebar").style.display = localStorage.getItem("chartSidebarStyle");
    }
};
```

Then set the item every time your function runs:

```
function chartButton() {
    var x = document.getElementById"chart_sidebar");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
        localStorage.setItem("chartSidebarStyle", "none");
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
        localStorage.setItem("chartSidebarStyle", "block");
    }
}
```

Now it will work even after you close the page, as long as you keep using the same browser to view the page (because localStorage only saves items to the browser you are using to view the web page).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help.